# Why the training loss is a stepped decreasing curve

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm training a classification model, and I keep getting training loss like this:

[image]

The validation loss is similar with the training loss:

[image]

I'm using `Adam` optimiser with its default settings, the initial learning rate is `0.01`, the loss function is cross-entropy loss.

I don't think the learning rate has changed during the training process, but why this stepped shape?

Comment: A plateau perhaps?

Comment: @gunes Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Thats a typical plateau.. a learning schedule with a larger learning rate in the beginning would probably help..
https://keras.io/api/callbacks/learning_rate_scheduler/

Comment: Are you using a learning rate scheduler? Can you share the code you're using to train the network? You described an "initial learning rate," and if the learning rate is decreased during training then this seems to be perfectly ordinary behavior. But if you're *not* using a scheduler, then hopefully the code will give a hint about why this pattern is observed.